# Find recursive relation of recursive sequence $a_{n+1}=1-\frac{a_{n}}{3}$

Tags: analysis

So I have recursive sequence $$a_{n+1}=1-\frac{a_{n}}{3}$$ with the first number $a_{1}=2$

So I have to find recursive relation for sub-sequence of even numbers $b_{n}=a_{2n}$ and recursive relation for sub-sequence of odd numbers $c_{n}=a_{2n-1}$

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

$b_{n+1}=a_{2n+2}=1-\frac {a_{2n+1}}{3}=1-\frac {1-\frac {a_{2n}}{3}}{3}=1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac {a_{2n}}{9}=\frac {2}{3} + \frac {b_n}{9}$
A very similar expansion gives the formula for c_n

Answer (score 1):

You have $$a_{n+2}=1-\frac{a_{n+1}}{3}$$
$$=1-\frac{1}{3}\Big(1-\frac{a_n}{3}\Big)$$
$$=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{a_n}{9}$$
Therefore,
$$a_{n+2}=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{a_n}{9}\forall n\in\mathbb N$$
Replace $n$ by $2n$ to get,
$$a_{2n+2}=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{a_{2n}}{9}$$
$$\Longrightarrow b_{n+1}=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{b_n}{9}$$
Similarly replace $n$ by $2n-1$ to get result for $c_n$.

**P.S.** In this particular situation, you can solve for $a_n$ in terms of $n$.
$$a_{n+2}=1-\frac{a_{n+1}}{3}$$
$$a_{n+1}=1-\frac{a_n}{3}$$
$$\Longrightarrow a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n-a_{n+1}}{3}$$
$$\Longrightarrow 3a_{n+2}-2a_{n+1}-a_n=0$$
Now find roots of corresponding quadratic equation and apply initial conditions to find general solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$a_{n+1}=1-\frac{a_{n}}{3}  
\\ \implies a_{n+2}= 1-\frac{a_{n+1}}{3} =\frac 23+\frac{a_n}{9}$$
so 
$$ b_{n+1}=\frac 23+\frac{b_n}{9};b_1=\frac 13$$
and

$$ c_{n+1}=\frac 23+\frac{c_n}{9};c_1=2$$

All three sequences converge to $\frac 34$

Answer (score 1):

Given $$A_{n+1}=1-\frac{A_n}{3}$$
Let $A_n=B_n+C$, then
$$B_{n+1}+C=1-\frac{B_n}{3}-\frac{C}{3} \implies B_{n+1}=1-\frac{4C}{3}-\frac{B_n}{3}$$
Let $1-4C/3=0 \implies C=3/4$, we get $$B_{n+1}=\frac{-1}{3} B_n \implies B_n= D\left(\frac{-1}{3}\right)^n \implies A_n=D\left(\frac{-1}{3}\right)^n +\frac{3}{4}$$
Given that $A_1=2$, we get $D=-\frac{15}{4}$, so finally
$$A_n=-\frac{15}{4}\left(\frac{-1}{3}\right)^n+\frac{3}{4}.$$